# Rising and Falling Edge in multiple signals - PYTHON

Tags: python, signal-processing, data-analysis

This is the global scenario: I'm recording some simple signals from a novel sensor using **Python 3.8**. I have already filtered signals to have a better representations where let run other algorithms of **Data Analysis**. Nothing of special.

Following some signals on which I need to run my algorithm:

[First Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvcSe.png)
[Second Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b81fo.png)

These signals came out a sensor whose I am working on. My aim is to **get the timestamps where signals starting to increase or decrease**. I actually need to run this algorithm for only one signal (blue or orange).
I have reported both signals because they have antagonistic behaviour and maybe could be useful to achieve my task.

In other words, these signals are regarded to Foot Flexion Extension (FLE/EXT), then the point where they start to increase represents the point when I start to move my foot. Viceversa, when I move back my foot it results on decreasing signals amplitude.

**My job is to identify the FLE/EXT** and I tried to examine first derivative but it appears to don't give me any useful information.
*I also have tried to use a convolution with a fixed-lenght ones-array by looking for when the  successive convulution's average is greater than the current one.*

This approach has 2 constraints:

- Fixed-lenght array: because when signals represents faster FLE/EXT (then in less temporale distance in x-axis) the window is not enough to catch variation.
- Threshold's Criterion for choosing how much has to be the successive average respect to the current one in order to save this iteration for my purpose.

I have stuck here, because *I want to use a dynamic threshold approach or something similar which can allow me to exclude any fixed thresholds.*

I hope to have a discussion with you for solving my problem. What do you think?
Please, if something is unclear, I am ready to clarify better.

Best regards,
V